# HTML - background image positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a problem about *background image positioning* in HTML5. I wanted to position my picture in the center and it did not work. This is the code I used in external CSS file:

```
body {
    background-image: url(logo.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

The same problem is with other two-word commands (example: "bottom left;"). Syntax is fine (checked multiple times) and still the same: 
[problem_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcfBB.png)

I don't understand the problem, please help?!

Comment: Try add this: `background-attachment: fixed;`

Comment: Try add `height: 100%` to css body as well.

Comment: @terryeah Thank you! This works! Can you explain because I'm beginner in HTML/CSS?!

Comment: More info on this topic https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: So, size of body is just size of your content, if you has only a image(50pxX50px) you body probably should has 50px height, got it?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `background-attachment: fixed`

Details:
The background-attachment property in CSS specifies how to move the background relative to the viewport.

There are three values: scroll, fixed, and local. The best way to explain this is via demo (try scrolling the individual backgrounds):

```css
@import "compass/css3";

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 48px;
}

div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 32px auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scroll {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/600/200/animals');
  background-attachment: scroll;
}

.fixed {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/600/200/animals');
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.local {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/600/200/animals');
  background-attachment: local;
}

.expand {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.extra-space {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h2><code>scroll (default)</code></h2>
<div class="scroll"><div class="expand"></div></div>

<h2><code>fixed</code></h2>
<div class="fixed"><div class="expand"></div></div>

<h2><code>local</code></h2>
<div class="local"><div class="expand"></div></div>

<br class="extra-space">
```

There are two different views to think about when talking about background-attachment: the main view (browser window), and the local view (you can see this in the demo above).

`scroll` is the default value. It scrolls with the main view, but stays fixed inside the local view.

`fixed` stays fixed no matter what. It's kind of like a physical window: moving around the window changes your perspective, but it doesn't change where things are outside of the window.

`local` was invented because the default scroll value acts like a fixed background. It scrolls both with the main view and the local view. There are some pretty cool things you can do with it.

[SOURCE](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-attachment/)

Answer (score 0):

if you add a height of 100vh to your body the background gets centered, check below snippet:

100vh - is the height of the viewport (the visible area of a web page)

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `html` and `body` elements are block level elements just like a `div`. Without a height explicitly set they simply will assume the height of their content, or with no content their height will be 0.

So you need to set the height of the `body` element to the same size as your viewport height to achieve your goal. The best way to do this would be to use viewport relative units:

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(logo.jpg) no-repeat center;
}
```

---

### Alternate method:

Another way to do it would be to first set the `html` **and** `body` height to 100%

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url(logo.jpg) no-repeat center;
}
```

You must set it on **both** as the `body` height is relative to the `html` height when using percentage units.

Answer (score 0):

you can use transform property to set image in center.You just need to call your image class in css and write this code.

```
 .imgclass{
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

This will set your image in the center of body. and if you are using bootstrap then just write `align-self-center` in your HTML image class.